Clarification on Gibbs Energy and Helmholtz Energy
According to what I have understood, ΔG for a reversible process (at constant temperature and pressure) represents the maximum non-mechanical work that a system can do, and ΔA is the maximum work a system can do isothermally. Apart from these (and the base definitions of A and G), is there any other difference in their significances and what they represent? Also, can it be said that the Gibbs energy (G) is a part of/contained in Helmholtz Energy (A) as ΔG represents maximum non-mechanical work and ΔA represents maximum isothermal work?

related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/170792/interpretation-of-helmholtz-energy-and-gibbs-energy?rq=1

Well, $G$ is not exactly "contained" in $A$  due to the fact that they are, in fact, exactly equivalent descriptions of a system (in different state variables coordinates). Look up at the relation between thermodynamics potentials, they are related by some cool mathematical trasformations that preserve all the information on the system (namely, the Legendre Transforms).

This question is similar to: Interpretation of Helmholtz and Gibbs energies?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
